# VB.net HTML {} placeholders replace with values

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, replace, stringbuilder

Hey all I am looking for a way to replace all my **{ZZZZZZ}** with whatever I need in a simple way.

Some of my HTML as an example:

```
Dim html As New StringBuilder("<table style=""border: none; width: 100%; font-size: 10px; 
                font-family: ""Helvetica Neue"", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"">" & _
  "<tr>" & _
     "<td style=""width: 30%; text-align: right;"">Your Name:</td>" & _
        "<td style=""width: 70%; text-align: left;"">{CI_NAME}</td>" & _
     "</tr>" & _
     "<tr>" & _
        "<td style=""text-align: right;"">Member:</td>" & _
     "<td style=""text-align: left;"">{CI_R2M}</td>" & _
  "</tr>" & _
  "<tr>" & _
     "<td style=""text-align: right;"">Your Phone #:</td>" & _
     "<td style=""text-align: left;"">{CI_PHONE}</td>" & _
  "</tr>" & _
  "<tr>" & _
     "<td style=""text-align: right;"">Your Email Address:</td>" & _
     "<td style=""text-align: left;"">{CI_EMAIL}</td>" & _
  "</tr>" & _
"</table>" & _
```

So in the example above, **{CI_NAME}**, **{CI_R2M}**, **{CI_PHONE}**, and **{CI_EMAIL}** are all the values I would need to replace with actual values.

Like so:

```
Dim html As New StringBuilder("<table style=""border: none; width: 100%; font-size: 10px; 
                font-family: ""Helvetica Neue"", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"">" & _
  "<tr>" & _
     "<td style=""width: 30%; text-align: right;"">Your Name:</td>" & _
        "<td style=""width: 70%; text-align: left;"">Bob Barker</td>" & _
     "</tr>" & _
     "<tr>" & _
        "<td style=""text-align: right;"">Member:</td>" & _
     "<td style=""text-align: left;"">Yes</td>" & _
  "</tr>" & _
  "<tr>" & _
     "<td style=""text-align: right;"">Your Phone #:</td>" & _
     "<td style=""text-align: left;"">555-802-3105</td>" & _
  "</tr>" & _
  "<tr>" & _
     "<td style=""text-align: right;"">Your Email Address:</td>" & _
     "<td style=""text-align: left;"">bobbarker@thepriceisright.com</td>" & _
  "</tr>" & _
"</table>" & _
```

I am not sure if the **StringBuilder** has any built in functions already or not?

I know there's something like this:

```
String.Format("Example ({0})", myString)
```

But that would have me making sure each variable matched up with the correct {} in order and would be hard to keep up with if I needed to add another {} or delete one. It would mess up the order and would have to re-due it all over each time.

Comment: I would suggest just using the `REPLACE()` function or create your own function that uses regex or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xml literal in your code (providing you are using a recent version of visual studio):

```
    Dim html = <table style=" border:none; width: 100%; font-size: 10px; font-family:Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
                   <tr>
                       <td style=" width:30%; text-align: right;">Your Name:</td>
                       <td style=" width:70%; text-align: left;">{CI_NAME}</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td style="text-align:right;">Member:</td>
                       <td style="text-align:left;">{CI_R2M}</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td style="text-align:right;">Your Phone #:</td>
                       <td style="text-align:left;">{CI_PHONE}</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td style="text-align:right;">Your Email Address:</td>
                       <td style="text-align:left;">{CI_EMAIL}</td>
                   </tr>
               </table>
```

You can then escape the values as a variable like this:

```
<td style="text-align:left;"><%= Somevariable %></td>
```

Comment: I'm using VS 2012 Ultimate edition. That sure looks like ASP to me?

Comment: You should be ok on that version. It's not asp, it is built into the IDE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396